# What's wrong with site layout under macos?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

Both in chrome and safari under macos layout of sites is often broken when browser is collapsed to half screen. This affects top sites too - facebook, google, apple store. However, it does not affect wikipedia or yandex.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Both safari and chrome use webkit engine on macos. Hypothesis: webkit is broken. Most probably, locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Adobe Flash Player. I've installed this monstrous thing and forgot.